# Integration test with testcontainers (Redis) Failing to run

Tags: docker, redis, testcontainers

I'm building integration test infrastructure for my micro-service (Java Spring).
Having an issue with testcontainers, as I try to create base class for tests that will start redis on container and will function as redis for the tested service.

the abstract test looks like this:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT)
public class AbstractRedisContainerTest {
    @Rule
    public GenericContainer redis = new GenericContainer("redis:3.0.6")
        .withExposedPorts(6379);
```

And my log show the follow fail msg:

```
2020-03-04 12:28:55.545 ERROR [myService,,,] 27709 --- [main] o.t.d.DockerClientProviderStrategy:
Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please check configuration. Attempted configurations were:
2020-03-04 12:28:55.546 ERROR [myService,,,] 27709 --- [main] o.t.d.DockerClientProviderStrategy:
EnvironmentAndSystemPropertyClientProviderStrategy: 
failed with exception InvalidConfigurationException (ping failed)
2020-03-04 12:28:55.546 ERROR [myService,,,] 27709 --- [main] o.t.d.DockerClientProviderStrategy:EnvironmentAndSystemPropertyClientProviderStrategy: 
failed with exception InvalidConfigurationException (ping failed)
2020-03-04 12:28:55.546 ERROR [myService,,,] 27709 --- [main] o.t.d.DockerClientProviderStrategy:UnixSocketClientProviderStrategy: 
failed with exception InvalidConfigurationException (ping failed). Root cause LastErrorException ([13])
2020-03-04 12:28:55.546 ERROR [myService,,,] 27709 --- [main] o.t.d.DockerClientProviderStrategy: ProxiedUnixSocketClientProviderStrategy: 
failed with exception InvalidConfigurationException (ping failed). Root cause TimeoutException (null)
2020-03-04 12:28:55.546 ERROR [myService,,,] 27709 --- [main] o.t.d.DockerClientProviderStrategy: As no valid configuration was found, execution cannot continue
org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Container startup failed
```

where this is the error for the failing line in the code:

```
Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerFetchException: Can't get Docker image:
RemoteDockerImage(imageNameFuture=java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@3186b07d[Completed normally],
imagePullPolicy=DefaultPullPolicy(), dockerClient=LazyDockerClient.INSTANCE)
```

Any idea how to configure my env or what missing here?
important to state that I have succeed to locally run docker images (the one stated here as well) and I have functioning docker environment from cli. I run this test from idea. 
not sure if that related, but I run it as user (not as root).